# Multiple masked images on top of each other using HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm pretty new to canvas and haven't worked with it before, but I thought it would be a good fit for the following task. While working on it, I got doubts and I still don't know if the task is even possible to implement using canvas.

Exemplary graphic of the masks and images and the result that I want to achieve (and the actual results that I got).

[image]

- The outlines are just there to better illustrate the images
  dimensions.
- The masks are SVG images which are preloaded using    promises before
  they are drawn and they change per iteration. So on    the first
  iteration it's mask A for image 1 and on the second    iteration mask
  B for image 2.

Simplified pseudocode example:

```
const items = [1, 2];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  ctx.drawImage(preloadedMask[i], x, y,  canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

  img[i] = new Image();
  img[i].onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out';
  };
  img[i].src = `images/${i+1}.jpg`;
}
```

When I remove the globalCompositeOperation and the images, the masks are perfectly drawn next to each other like I expected.
But as soon as I add a globalCompositeOperation it gets complicated, and I am super confused to be honest.

I tried every possible globalCompositeOperation value in the onload callback - but it doesn't change much. I think I have to change the globalCompositeOperation after the mask is drawn for each iteration to a different value - but I am out of ideas.

Is there any way to achieve my desired output as described in the graphic, or should I ditch canvas for this task?

Comment: An alternative approach may be to extract the SVG path definition and use that to construct a path2d object which you can then stamp into the canvas. The images can be added by using them as patterns for each path's fillStyle. Or, if you know the SVG outlines will always be hemispheres, just use an arc to create the path and fill with the appropriate image as a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve isn't that easy unfortunately - at least if you're using SVGs which are treated as images and directly drawn to the canvas.

Suppose we have the following svg masks and images

[image]

If we take the first mask and the first image and use the following code:

```
context.drawImage(maskA,0,0,width,height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
context.drawImage(imageA,0,0,width,height);
```

we get the desired output:

[image]

If we repeat the process and do the same for the second mask:

```
context.drawImage(maskB,0,0,width,height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
context.drawImage(imageB,0,0,width,height);
```

we'll just see an empty canvas. Why? We set globalCompositeOperation to 'source-in' and the previous canvas and the second mask (maskB) don't have any overlapping regions. That means we're effectively erasing the canvas.

If we try to compensate and either save/restore the context or reset globalCompositeOperation to it's initial state

```
context.save();
context.drawImage(maskA,0,0,width,height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
context.drawImage(imageA,0,0,width,height);
context.restore();
context.drawImage(maskB,0,0,width,height);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
context.drawImage(imageB,0,0,width,height);
```

we still don't succeed:

[image]

So the trick here is this:

- make sure both the svgs and images to be masked are fully loaded
- create a new empty canvas the size of your target canvas
- draw the first mask onto the new canvas
- set it's globalCompositeOperation to 'source-in'
- draw the first image onto the new canvas
- draw the new canvas to the target canvas
- erase the new canvas and repeat the previous steps to compose your final image

Here's an example (just click 'Run code snippet'):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let imagesLoaded = 0;
let imageA = document.getElementById("imageA");
let imageB = document.getElementById("imageB");
let width = canvas.width;
let height = canvas.height;

function loaded() {
  imagesLoaded++;
  if (imagesLoaded == 4) {
    let tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tempCanvas.width = width;
    tempCanvas.height = height;
    tempContext.save();
    tempContext.drawImage(document.getElementById("semiCircleA"), 0, 0, width, height);
    tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    tempContext.drawImage(imageA, 0, 0, width, 160);
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);

    tempContext.restore();
    tempContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    tempContext.drawImage(document.getElementById("semiCircleB"), 0, 0, width, height);
    tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    tempContext.drawImage(imageB, 0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

document.getElementById("semiCircleA").onload = loaded;
document.getElementById("semiCircleB").onload = loaded;

imageA.onload = loaded;
imageA.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/160/160";

imageB.onload = loaded;
imageB.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/137/160/160";
```

```html
<h1>Final Canvas</h1>
<canvas id="canvas" width=160 height=160>
</canvas>
<br>
<h1>Sources</h1>
<img id="semiCircleA" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
  <path d="M80,0 A80,80 0 0,0 80,160"/>
</svg>'>
<img id="semiCircleB" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
  <path d="M80,0 A80,80 0 0,1 80,160"/>
</svg>'>
<img id="imageA">
<img id="imageB">
```

Comment: I Appreciate the comprehensive example and explanation. This ultimately solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

### A canvas can be a layer

The canvas like any element is easy to create and can be treated like an image, or if you are familiar with photoshop, a canvas can be a layer.

To create a blank canvas

```
// Returns the renderable image (canvas)
function CreateImage(width, height) {
    return Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {width, height});
}
```

To copy a canvas or image like object

```
// Image can be any image like element including canvas. Returns the renderable image 
function CopyImage(img, width = img.width, height = img.height, smooth = true) {
    const can = createImage(width, height});
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    can.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = smooth;
    can.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    return can;
}
```

### Loading

Never load images in a render loop. The image `onload` event will not respect the order you assign the `src`. Thus the rendering of images in `onload` will not always be in the order you wish.

Load all images and wait before rendering.

An example of loading a set of images. The function `loadImages` returns a promise that will resolve when all images have loaded.

```
const images = {
    maskA: "imageUrl",
    maskB: "imageUrl",
    imgA: "imageUrl",
    imgB: "imageUrl",
};
function loadImages(imgList, data) {
    return new Promise((done, loadingError) => {
        var count = 0;
        const imgs = Object.entries();
        for (const [name, src] of imgs) {
            imgList[name] = new Image;
            imgList[name].src = src;
            count ++;
            imgList[name].addEventListener("load", () => {
                    count--;
                    if (count === 0) { done({imgs: imgList, data}) }
                }, {once, true)
            );
            imgList[name].addEventListener("error", () => {
                    for (const [name, src] of imgs) { imgList[name] = src } 
                    loadingError(new Error("Could not load all images"));
                }, {once, true)
            );
        }
    });
}
```

### Rendering

It is best to create functions to do repeated tasks. One task you are repeating is masking, the following function uses a canvas as a destination, an image, and a mask

```
function maskImage(ctx, img, mask, x = 0, y = 0, w = ctx.canvas.height, h = ctx.canvas.width, clear = true) {
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
     clear && ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.height, ctx.canvas.width);
     ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
     ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
     ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, w, h);
     return ctx.canvas;  // return the renderable image 
}
```

Once you have some utilities set up to help coordinate the loading and rendering you can composite your finial result

```
// assumes ctx is the context to render to
loadImages(images, {ctx}).then(({imgs, {ctx}} => {
    const w = ctx.canvas.width, h = ctx.canvas.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    const layer = copyImage(ctx.canvas);
    ctx.drawImage(maskImage(layer.ctx, imgs.imgA, imgs.maskA), 0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.drawImage(maskImage(layer.ctx, imgs.imgB, imgs.maskB), 0, 0, w, h);

    // if you no longer need the images always remove them from memory to avoid hogging
    // client's resources.
    imgs = {}; // de-reference images so that GC can clean up.

}
```

You can now layer as many masked images as needed. Because functions where created for each sub task it is easy to create more complicated rendering without needing to write verbose and repeated code, in both this project and future projects.